# Необходимо ли ставить двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

"Нужно ли ставить двоеточие после слова "красители"? "Содержит красители бриллиантовый черный, пунцовый [Понсо 4R], азорубин"? или "Содержит красители: бриллиантовый черный, пунцовый [Понсо 4R], азорубин"?

Answer (score 2):

Лучше поставить двоеточие, чтобы обозначить перечисление (иначе текст читается недостаточно ясно).

*Содержит **красители**: бриллиантовый черный, пунцовый [Понсо 4R], азорубин.*

Здесь пропущено слово "следующие" с обобщающим значением, но это допускается правилами http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103 (пункт 3).

Написание **без двоеточия** тоже возможно, если пользователям понятен текст. Тогда можно считать, что красители  — это определяемое слово (родовое наименование)  перед рядом приложений (названий). http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103 (пункт 4).